How to enforce that all queries must include a partition filter in databricks delta table
I want to know if is it possible to enforce that all queries must include a partition filter if the delta table is a partition table in databricks?
I tried the below option and set the required property but it doesn't work and I can query test_table without passing the partition clause in the where condition.
ALTER TABLE test_table SET TBLPROPERTIES ('partitioned'='true', 'partitioned.query.required'='true');
Please let me know if it is doable in delta table.

are you using azure databricks
